# asterisk confbridge and answering machine detection

Tags: asterisk, telephony

I have an outbound conferencing system using asterisk. I call all the participants and connect them to music on hold. when the last participant answers I start the ConfBridge application.

I want to know if the call to the last participant was answered by a human or voicemail, and I thought about using the AMD application. Is it possible to run this application after starting the ConfBridge app?

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk call usually have 2 channels

There are no any issues start one channel to confbridge other to AMD

You also can improve confbridge( expert/god-like c/c++ skill required) to do what you needed.

Comment: I have to start ConfBridge as soon as the last participant answers, and as far as I understand the call to ConfBridge from the dialplan is synchronous, so I can't call AMD afterwards. The only solution I came up with is what you suggested - take the logic from the AMD app and integrate it with the ConfBridge app.

Comment: You can call AMD on other leg of call. Also it seams usless for me do confbirdge after that AMD,usually it have sense do via vesa: first AMD,after that Confbridge if human.

Comment: The other participants have to hear everything the last participants says. This means that I have to put him in the conf bridge as soon as he joins. Otherwise, if I run AMD and only then join the conference the other participants may not hear what he says until AMD is done.

Comment: If so,other participants WILL hear voicemail,no? If you insist, you can do AMD in other thread connected via chanspy. However anyway seams such setup go far beyond your asterisk skill. You have learn more(maybe some curses?) or hire expert.

Comment: I have no problem with the other participants hearing voicemail. if you explain the setup to me I believe I can do it. How can I fork the call to two threads?

Comment: Create enother call(google asterisk dialout) and bind it via chanspy command.